# How to dispaly resources and events from database to fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I've been developing a full-calendar with a resource column and draggable events. I'm stuck at displaying the resources and events from the database on the calendar.

The data could be fetched successfully, as I can see it in the response tab in an array but it is not getting displayed on the calendar at all. Even the front-end doesn't seem to be working fully as while adding the resource, it is not even getting displayed temporarily. The files are getting called in the network tabs and I can see the correct results in the response tab, so I'm guessing it's the display that is not working maybe I haven't installed proper plugins or something. Can you please check what is wrong? 
There were a few similar questions on this site, but everyone seemed to have different issues. I can post other related files as well, let me know if you would like to see.
Here's the code:

````
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   var containerEl = document.getElementById("external-events");
   var checkbox = document.getElementById("drop-remove");
   new FullCalendarInteraction.Draggable(containerEl, {
   itemSelector: ".fc-event",
   eventData: function(eventEl) {
     return {
       title: eventEl.innerText
     };
   }
   });
   var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
   var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
   schedulerLicenseKey: "GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source",
   plugins: ["interaction", "resourceTimeline"],
   header: {
     left: "promptResource today prev,next",
     center: "title",
     right: "resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek"
   },
   customButtons: {
     promptResource: {
       text: "+ room",
       click: function() {
         var title = prompt("Room name");
         console.log(title);
         if (title) {
           fetch("add_resources.php", {
               method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'text/html' 
                },
                body: encodeFormData({"title": title}),
                 }) 
                   .then(response => response.text())
                .then(response => { 
               calendar.addResource({
             id: response,
             title: title
           });

           })
             .catch(error => console.log(error));
         }
       }
     }
   },
   editable: true,
   aspectRatio: 1.5,
   defaultView: "resourceTimelineDay",
   resourceLabelText: "Rooms",
   resources: "all_resources.php",
   droppable: true,
   drop: function(info) {
     if (checkbox.checked) {
       info.draggedEl.parentNode.removeChild(info.draggedEl);
     }
   },
   eventLimit: true,
   events: "all_events.php",
   displayEventTime: false,
   eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
     if (event.allDay === "true") {
       event.allDay = true;
     } else {
       event.allDay = false;
     }
   },
   selectable: true,
   selectHelper: true,
   eventReceive: function(info) {
     console.log(calendar.getResources());
     console.log(info.event);
     var eventData = {
       title: info.event.title,
       start: moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
       end: moment(info.event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
       resourceid: info.event._def.resourceIds[0]
     };

     console.log(eventData);
     //send the data via an AJAX POST request, and log any response which comes from the server
     fetch("add_event.php", {
       method: "POST",
       headers: {
         Accept: "application/json"
       },
       body: encodeFormData(eventData)
     })
       .then(response => console.log(response))
       .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
    });
    calendar.render();
   });

     const encodeFormData = data => {
     var form_data = new FormData();

    for (var key in data) {
      form_data.append(key, data[key]);
    }
    return form_data;
   };

form.php

    <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/interaction@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timegrid@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
   <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-common@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
     <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script> 
   <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src='main.js'></script>
   <div id='external-events'>
    <p>
   <strong>Draggable Events</strong>
   </p>
    <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
    <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
    <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
    <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
    <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
    <p>
   <input type='checkbox' id='drop-remove' />
   <label for='drop-remove'>remove after drop</label>
   </p>
   </div>
  <div id='calendar-container'>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </div>

all_resources.php        

    <?php
     require 'connection.php';
      $conn = DB::databaseConnection();
      $json = array();
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM resources ORDER BY resourceId";
     $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
     $result->execute();
      $alldata = array();
       while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
     {
      array_push($alldata, $row);
     }
     echo json_encode($alldata);
      ?> ``` 

   all_events.php

   <?php
   require 'connection.php';
   $conn = DB::databaseConnection();
   $json = array();
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY id";
   $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $result->execute();
   $alldata = array();
   while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
   {
     array_push($alldata, $row);
   }
   echo json_encode($alldata);
    ?>
````

The response from `all_resources.php` looks like this:

```
[
  {"resourceId":"104","resourceTitle":"TESET"},
  {"resourceId":"105","resourceTitle":"AA"},
  {"resourceId":"106","resourceTitle":"HM"},
  {"resourceId":"107","resourceTitle":"TEST"}
]
```

The response from `all_events.php` looks like this:

```
[
  {"id":"65","resourceId":"104","title":"My Event 1","start":"2020-04-06","end":"2020-04-06"},
  {"id":"66","resourceId":"105","title":"My Event 1","start":"2020-04-06","end":"2020-04-06"}
]
```

Comment: _"I can see it in the response tab in an array"_...please show us what it looks like then. If you provide data which is not valid in some way, fullCalendar may not always show an error but it will just ignore it.

Comment: So when I refresh the page, the all_resources.php and all_events.php gets loaded in the network panel. For the all_resources.php, the response looks like this - {"JSON":[{"resourceId":"104","resourceTitle":"TESET"},{"resourceId":"105","resourceTitle":"AA"},{"resourceId":"106","resourceTitle":"HM"},{"resourceId":"107","resourceTitle":"TEST"}],
And same is for the all_events.php. 
If there's any other way I can show you the response, please let me know

Comment: In this: `{"JSON":[{"resourceId":"104","resourceTitle":"TESET"},{"resourceId":"105","resourceTitle":"AA"},{"resourceId":"106","resourceTitle":"HM"},{"resourceId":"107","resourceTitle":"TEST"}]` the `{"JSON":` bit is the main issue. In the case of both resources and events you must return _just_ an array, and nothing else. If you wrap it inside an object like that, fullCalendar does not know where in your object to look for the data.

Comment: Secondly, your resource objects do not conform to the specification set out by fullCalendar. The property names do not match. Read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-parsing please. What names does it require you to use for the properties? Why didn't you use them? After all you have seen all the examples in the demos etc, even if you never read that page before. Did you think fullCalendar can guess which of your random property names is supposed to be the ID, and which is the title, and which is the colour, etc etc?? It's not logical. Computers cannot guess or infer in the way humans can...

Comment: ...the computer cannot infer that `"resourceTitle": "TESET"` must actually mean `"title": "TESET"` because "oh, it's a resource object, so it must be that". It can't think like that. You might as well have written `"wsjhkjhgjer": "TESET"`. It has no more or less meaning to fullCalendar than `resourceTitle`. You have to be precise and stick to the documented names.

Comment: Anyway the JSON you send for resources needs to be like this: `[{"id":"104","title":"TESET"},{"id":"105","title":"AA"},{"id":"106","title":"HM"},{"id":"107","title":"TEST"}]` - i.e. with the correct property names, and without the outer object. I assume you may have made similar mistakes with the event data, so please check that as well. Fullcalendar's specification for how it reads an event object is documented here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing

Comment: P.S. it's unclear, from the all_resources.php code, how the `{"JSON":` bit got there, it doesn't seem reproducible from the code. But whatever, I'll take your word for it. Either way you certainly need to ensure it doesn't appear again.

Comment: Okay I get what you're saying. It's the resources that I've not coded according to the specifications by fullCalendar. But can you check the all_events.php part up there in the code? I tried doing it the same way I had done for the fullCalendar that I had developed without the resources. And for the above code, the output for the all_events.php is like this: {"JSON":[{"id":"65","resourceId":"104","title":"My Event 1","start":"2020-04-06","end":"2020-04-06"},{"id":"66","resourceId":"105","title":"My Event 1","start":"2020-04-06","end":"2020-04-06"}]

Comment: Similarly again, that first bit `{"JSON":` should not be there. You need to provide the array only. Again though it's unclear from the code how that extra data has actually got there. The PHP as shown doesn't look like it would do that.

Comment: Hey! That's just like a heading in the response tab. It's not the part of the output but it is just a heading there. I've to use the click to copy the response from there, hence it got copied as well.

Comment: How do I use the names for the properties according to the fullcalendar?

Comment: I tried using the eventRender function but the problem that I faced while using that is 1. It's already being used in the code, I can't use it again for the resources otherwise the editor is showing me an error there saying duplicate property name. 2. I still tried testing the following for now, ( ```  resources: "all_resources.php",eventRender: function(info) { console.log(info.event.title);     
    })```
but there's no output in the console.

Comment: ??? How would eventRender help with resources? Not sure what you're thinking of there exactly. And eventRender only runs if there already some events.

Comment: Okay. Do I specify the resourceId by using getResourceById? But I'm not sure how do I use it there.

Comment: No. That _gets_ the resource ID, not _sets_ it. If you're asking how to change the PHP so that it changes the all_resources.php code to use the correct property names, be patient, I will post something in a bit

Comment: P.S. your existing `eventRender` code is _still_ wrong and won't do what you expect it to, (despite it being mentioned before - check our previous discussion for details.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resource data is not in the format specified by fullCalendar. The field names you supply in the JSON must be *exactly* as mentioned in the [resource parsing documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-parsing) - e.g. `id` for the resource ID, `title` for the title, etc. If you don't do this, fullCalendar cannot understand the data and will not display the resources.

To modify your server-side code to achieve this you have two options:

1) change your database column names in your `resources` table to match what fullCalendar requires. So you'd change `resourceId` to `id` and `resourceTitle` to `title`. This should be sufficient, and would not require any changes to your PHP code.

**OR**

2) change your `all_resources.php` PHP code so it generates a new array for each data row, containing the same data but with different property names, so that these names will be encoded in the JSON instead of the column names from the database:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
$conn = DB::databaseConnection();
$json = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM resources ORDER BY resourceId";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();
$alldata = array();
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $resource = array(
    "id" => $row["resourceId"],
    "title" => $row["resourceTitle"]
  );
  array_push($alldata, $resource);
}

echo json_encode($alldata);
?>
```

Comment: Worked!!! Thank you so much!!
The only problem I'm getting now is that the event is showing all day, like from 6am to 11pm. Even though I drop it in an hour time frame, after refresh it will be visible for all day.

Comment: Will changing the datatype from date to datetime work?

Comment: That's likely to help yes - otherwise the database cannot store the information about the time of day, which means it'll be lost when you try to reload the event data from the database.

Comment: Yes. That was it. Thank you :)